# Use docker-compose for NodeJS and SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, docker-compose, connection

I have the `docker-compose.yml` below:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
   sql-server-db:
     container_name: sql-server-db
     image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
     ports:
       - "1433:1433"
     environment:
       SA_PASSWORD: "Thieu@098551298"
       ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

I will run command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I used 2 command to go my database

```
$ docker exec -it sql-server-db "bash"
$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -s localhost -U SA -P Thieu@098551298

1> select name from sys.databases
2> go
name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master
tempdb
model
msdb
```

Then I will create and insert data:

```
1> create database blog
2> go
1> use blog
2> go
Changed database context to 'blog'.
1> create table post (id int,title nvarchar(100),content nvarchar(100))
2> go
1> insert into post values(1,"How to learn docker"," qwe qwje qwb ejqwbe bqwe bqwe bqwje jkqwn e")
2> go

(1 rows affected)
1> select *from post
2> go
id         ltitle                                                                                               lcontent                   

-----------l----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------l----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          1lHow to learn docker                                                                                 l qwe qwje qwb ejqwbe bqwe bqwe bqwje jkqwn e

(1 rows affected)
1>
```

When I have the database above I write:

```
var sql = require('mssql')

var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'Thieu@098551298',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: "blog",
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true,
        trustServerCertificate: true
    }
}

function ExecuteSQL(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(config, (err, db) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(query, (err, db) => {
                if (err) reject(err);
                resolve(db);
            });
        })
    })
}
async function z(){
    var z = await ExecuteSQL("select *from post")
    console.log(z.recordsets)
}
z()
```

It will throw an error:

> ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Purpose: I want to display the data I just added, but it seems to connect to SQL Server on my machine so is there any way I can connect to Docker SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: The database and table in your SQL setup code are different than those in your NodeJS code. Do you also create the `Quizz` database?

Comment: sorry I forgot to edit the file before posting, I've fixed it but still the same error

Comment: Did you try with SA in uppercase in your config file ? since you can connect with `-U SA`

Comment: Is the NodeJS code running on the Docker host, or inside another Docker container (inside the same Docker network)? From a container's point of view, `localhost` is itself. Try specifying `server: 'sql-server-db'` instead.

Comment: I was Try specifying server: 'sql-server-db' instead. It will throw a err: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to sql-server-db:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND sql-server-db

Comment: I was solve when I delelte SQL Server Management Studio, and the nodejs file will connect to sql server container, thanks every one

Answer (score -1):

I was solve when I delelte SQL Server Management Studio, and the nodejs file will connect to sql server container, thanks everyone